# How to Map another Serializable Class in onResponse of Retrofit2.?

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, android-networking

```
 Call<LoginResponse> call = apiService.register(email, mob);
 call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {

                    if(response.code()==200){
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        LoginResponse phoneLoginResponse = response.body();
                        String sPhoneLoginRes = gson.toJson(phoneLoginResponse, LoginResponse.class);
                        Log.d(TAG, "JSON RESPONSE IS" + sPhoneLoginRes);
                   }else if(response.code()==401){

   //here i want to show below Response
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        ErrorResponse errorResponse = response.body();
                        String sPhoneLoginRes = gson.toJson(errorResponse.toString(), LoginResponse.class);
                        Log.d(TAG, "JSON RESPONSE IS" + sPhoneLoginRes);
                  }else if(response.code()==400){
                        Toast.makeText(SignUpActivity.this, "Somethign went Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }



                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<LoginResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                }
            });
```

This is what my 401 Response,when i tried submitting the form agian ,i need to get the below Object ,so i make use of ErrorResponse Class.But Response i am getting is Null.Please help me out.

```
{
  "message": "string",
  "errors": [
    "string"
  ]
}
```

I am using Retrofit2.0

Answer (score 0):

`Response.body()` returns `null` if `Response.isSuccessful()` is false. It will be false for any non-2xx response code.

You will need to use `Response.errorBody()` to retrieve the raw response and parse that yourself.

Comment: can you elobrate the stuff or programmatic approach Would be appreciated !! Thanks

Comment: To get the raw JSON use `response.errorBody().string()`. From there its entirely up to you.

Comment: should I map this to any class ? Like                             LoginResponse res =response.errorBody().toString().

Answer (score 0):

i got solution for what i am looking .

```
                     //request not successful (like 400,401,403 etc)
                        //Handle errors
     Converter<ResponseBody, ErrorResponse> converter = ApiClient.getRetrofit().responseBodyConverter(ErrorResponse.class, new Annotation[0]);
                     try {
                            ErrorResponse errors = converter.convert(response.errorBody());
                            dialogUtil.showOkDialog(errors.getMessage().toString());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            dialogUtil.showOkDialog(e.getMessage().toString());
                        }
```